# Proof of Sine not converging

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

While trying to prove that sin(x) is not convergent via proof by contradiction:

Suppose the limit exists:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sin(x) = L$$
Then:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \cos(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{1-\sin(x)^2} = \sqrt{1-L^2}$$
Since:
$$\sin(90-x)=\cos(x)$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \cos(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty} \sin(90-x) = \lim_{x\to -\infty} \sin(x) = -L \text{ (by symmetry)}$$
So: $$-L = \sqrt{1-L^2}$$
$$2L^2=1$$ $$L = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
It does not seem to give any contradiction. Which part of this proof is incorrect?

Comment: $L$ must be $\le0$ in order to square both sides

Comment: Why? Please elaborate, which step are you explicitly referring to?

Comment: In a similar vein, we cannot write $\cos(x)=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}$ unless $\cos(x)\geq 0$.

Comment: In the last three steps, you must have $-L\ge 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the proof is incorrect. You have correctly proven the statement

> If $L=\lim_{x\to\infty} \sin(x)$, then $2L^2=1$.

The statement is perfectly correct, as is the statement "If $1=2$, then elephants are lizards". In other words, the statement is vacuously true.

---

However, the statement **in no way** says that the sine function converges. To better prove the fact that the function does not converge, try to find a sequence $x_1, x_2,x_3,\dots$ such that

1. $\lim_{i\to\infty} x_i=\infty$.
2. $\lim_{i\to\infty} f(x_i)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

A way to prove it doesn't converges : Suppose it does and denote $L$ its limit. Since $$\sin(x+2)=\sin(x)+2\sin(1)\cos(x+1),$$
it implies that the cosine function also converges at infinity, and it converges to $0$.

Moreover, since
$$\cos(x+2)=\cos(x)-2\sin(1)\sin(x+1),$$
you get that the sinus function also converges to $0$. Finally, since
$$\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1,$$

taking $x\to \infty $ gives $0=1$, which is a contradiction.

---

However, this proof is interesting only if you are restricted on the argument of the sine and cosine being in $\mathbb N$. In your case,  since the argument is real, you have that $$\sin(n\pi)=0\quad \text{and}\quad \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi\right)=1,$$
for all $n$, and thus the non convergence of the sine function is straightforward.